# Parabolic shape css

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a parabolic shape using CSS. By this I mean 
this target shape:

[image: Target]

I'd like the shape to be one solid color. The code beneath is what I've managed so far, it makes a half circle.

```
.circle::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #22222A;
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 80px;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 2.5vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 90px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know what you are looking for exactly.

```css
.circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 110px;
    border-top-right-radius: 110px;
    border: 10px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 0;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining border radius with respect to the width and height of the element. In addition, you hide the border on the top.

```css
.parabola{
  width:200px; height:200px;  
  border:solid;
  border-color:transparent #000 #000 #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parabola"></div>
```

View the codepen here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOYjJO

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in either way

```
 <div class="circle"></div>
```

```css
.circle{
  height : 200px;
  width : 300px;
  border : 1px solid red;
  border-radius : 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"> 
</div>
```

```
  .circle{
  height : 300px;
  width : 200px;
  border : 1px solid red;
  border-radius : 50%;
}
```